# Does Cop Craft continue after the anime in the light novel?

Tags: cop-craft

So the anime of Cop Craft is not releasing more episodes for now. The anime had some sort of conclusion where one of the main evil characters died but it was very short. Does Cop Craft continue after the anime in the light novel?